# Bad Request when trying to call REST API with basic authentication - C#

Tags: json, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

Hi i'm creating a console application that calls a REST web API. Following is the my current code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string URL = "https://testweb/";
        string JSON_IN = "{'parameters':" +
                            "[" +
                            "{" +
                            "'value': {'string':{ 'value': 'barba2'}}," +
                            "'type': 'string'," +
                            "'name': 'vmName'" +
                            "}," +
                            "{" +
                            "'value':{'string':{'value': 'ctx-poc-null'}}," +
                            "'type': 'string'," +
                            "'name': 'securityTagName'" +
                            "}" +
                            "]}";
        string userName = "user";
        string password = "password";

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        Uri requestUri = new Uri(URL);

        // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(String.Format("{0}:{1}", userName, password))));

        // List data response.
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(requestUri,new StringContent(JSON_IN, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;  // Blocking call!
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nop");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Unfortunately this gives mean continuous error like follow.

```
{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
```

{
  Connection: close
  Date: Mon, 19 Sep 2016 11:10:27 GMT
  Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
  Content-Length: 1032
  Content-Language: en
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
}}

Here i'm using POST method with basic authentication. I have tried many examples given in internet. but most of them are not clear for me. Please help me with the problem.

Comment: I would use some framework for building out the json or use the extension method `PostAsJsonAsync` on `HttpClient`, since building the content by hand can be tricky.